# Is it possible to "extend" the property "class"?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, properties

I'm new to C# (started last week) so be cool with me ;).
I'd like to know if I can somehow write a custom property, let me explain:

I have some partial classes that I complete by adding properties,  but the pattern of all the getters and setters are the same so I'd like to factorize this:

```
public partial class Travel
{
    public String TravelName
    {
        get
        {
            return LocaleHelper.GetRessource(Ressource1);
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Ressource1 == null)
                Ressource1 = new Ressource() { DefaultValue = value };
            else
                Ressource1.DefaultValue = value;
        }
    }

    public String TravelDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return LocaleHelper.GetRessource(Ressource2);
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.Ressource2 == null)
                Ressource2 = new Ressource() { DefaultValue = value };
            else
                Ressource2.DefaultValue = value;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the only thing that change is Ressource1/Ressource2.
My goal is be able to write something like:

```
public partial class Travel
{
    public LocalizedString TravelName(Ressource1);

    public LocalizedString TravelDescription(Ressource2);
}
```

Anybody have an idea to make this, or another idea to make my code cleaner?
Thank you,

Guillaume

Comment: Are you aware of System.Globalization namespace/concepts?

Comment: Yes but what i found on the web about using a database to store ressource data is very "confusing" (headache)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no facility to do this inside C# or .NET itself, but if you are doing lots of these it may be worth investigating aspect orientated programming through [postsharp](http://www.postsharp.org/). Basically it will allow you to define an attribute that causes extra code to be injected at compile time. The code you type be something like:

```
public partial class Travel
{
    [LocalizedProperty(source = "Ressource1")
    public string TravelName { get; set; }

    [LocalizedProperty(source = "Ressource2")
    public string TravelDescription{ get; set; }
}
```

And at compile time PostSharp will replace the property with a template you have defined in the new LocalizedPropertyAttribute class.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make it *quite* as succinct as what you describe, but you can decrease the complexity and redundancy of the setters.

```
private void SetRessource(ref Ressource res, string value)
{
    if(res == null) res = new Ressource();

    res.DefaultValue = value;
}

public String TravelName
{
    get { return LocaleHelper.GetRessource(Ressource1); }
    set { SetRessource(ref this.Ressource1, value); }
}

public String TravelDescription
{
    get { return LocaleHelper.GetRessource(Ressource2); }
    set { SetRessource(ref this.Ressource2, value); }
}
```

Comment: Good idea.  An extra suggestion is to make the get, set and the Ressource member part of an interface, say INameProvider.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you are trying to achieve, but you may be making things too complicated. Wouldn't this be sufficient?

```
public class Travel
{
   /// <summary>
   /// Creates a new instance of <see cref="Travel"/>.
   /// </summary>
   public Travel()
   {
      this.TravelName = Resources.DefaultTravelName;
      this.TravelDescription = Resources.DefaultTravelDescription;
   }

   public string TravelName { get; set; }

   public string TravelDescription { get; set; }
}
```

where Resources is a generated class (from a resx file) for localized resources. I have a feeling you are trying to build your own localization framework because you don't know yet that .NET [already has infrastructure for that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3xbc3357%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Actually Ressources are Linq to SQL entities with "en", "fr", "es" etc String fields. My LocaleHelper.GetRessource(Ressource) returns the right language.
(I need to have the ressources in a database and i tried to use the default globalization system, it's hell to use a db in place of resx...).
My custom properties are there to make me able to make nice LINQ requests and databindings.

Comment: btw your solution is perfect for the get part, but unfortunaly the set part is a little more complex...

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such way. It would be [possible in php](http://ua.php.net/__callstatic) but not in C#.

You should change your approach away from properties in this case.

UPD:
Probably you could use something like this for every property (except for it's obvious weakness):

```
public class Prop
{
    Resource _res;

    public Prop(Resource res)
    {
        this._res = res;
    }

    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return LocaleHelper.GetRessource(_res);
        }
        set
        {
            if(_res == null)
                // This is a weak point as it's now
                // as it wont work
            else
                _res.DefaultValue = value;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a single indexed property, giving you one of the following two syntax choices based on your preference.  The code would basically be a function that accepts the specifically named resource and returns the right content.

```
Travel t = new Travel();
string x = t["Name"];
    or 
string x = t[Travel.Name];
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make your life easier by encapsulating your getter and setter logic in a base class and then simply calling those methods from any new properties you create (simply acting as thin wrapper around those methods). Here's an example:

```
public class Travel : LocalizedRessourceSubscriber
{

    private Ressource<string> Ressource1 = null;
    private Ressource<string> Ressource2 = null;

    public String TravelName { 
        get { return GetRessource<string>(Ressource2); }
        set { SetRessource<string>(Ressource1, value); } 
    }

    public String TravelDescription {
        get { return GetRessource<string>(Ressource2); }
        set { SetRessource<string>(Ressource2, value); } 
    }

}

public class LocalizedRessourceSubscriber
{

    protected T GetRessource<T>(Ressource<T> Source)
    {
        return LocaleHelper.GetRessource<T>(Source);
    }

    protected void SetRessource<T>(Ressource<T> Source, T Value)
    {
       (Source ?? 
           (Source = new Ressource<T>())
                ).DefaultValue = Value;
    }

}
```

...This way, there is very little logic in your properties and you are repeating less code. This assumes the following  classes (which I mocked as genericized):

```
public static class LocaleHelper
{
    public static T GetRessource<T>(Ressource<T> Source)
    {
        return default(T);
    }
}

public class Ressource<T>
{
    public T DefaultValue { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

That doesn't make sense.
using propertys the way you currently have them, you can simply write:

```
   Travel t = new Travel();
   string tvlName = t.TravelName;    
   string desc = t.TravelDescription;
```

If you changed to the way you want you'd have to specify the parameter as well

```
   Travel t = new Travel();
   LocalizedString tvlName = t.TravelName([someresopurcedesignator]);    
   LocalizedString desc = t.TravelDescription([someresopurcedesignator]);
```

all you could do is make a "propertyBag" emulator

```
   public class Travel 
   {
       private LocalizedString props = new LocalizedString();
       public LocalizedString Propertys
       {
          get { return props; }
          set { props = value; }
       }

   }

   public class LocalizedString // this is property Bag emulator
   {
       public string this[string resourceName]
       {
           get{ return LocaleHelper.GetRessource(resourceName); }
           set{ LocaleHelper.GetRessource(resourceName) = value; }
       }
   }
```

You would access this like this:

```
   Travel t = new Travel();
   t.Propertys[NameResource1] = "Bob Smith";
   t.Propertys[DescriptionResource2] = "Fun trip to discover the orient";
   string tvlName = t.Propertys[NameResource1];    
   string desc    = t.Propertys[DescriptionResource2];
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the OPs intent. His syntax is not suggesting that the calls to the property become parameterized; he merely wants the implementation to be parameterized.

Comment: @Jeff, Then perhaps I still misunderstand... If the implementation is parameterized, how can the parameter value get to the implementation if the calls are not parameterized?